# Has_many through with a parameter in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am struggling to manage a join table that has an integer whose purpose is to be used as an index or label over the associated records. Lets say the join table is

```
class Pair < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner
  belongs_to :element 
  validates_presence_of :position
end
```

With the implied setup

```
class Element < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :pairs
   has_many :owners through :pairs  
end

class Owner < ...
   has_many :pairs
   has_many :elements through :pairs
end
```

and position being a weight or index that ranks the elements owned by an owner

Now I want, on the collection `owner.elements`:

1. Select exactly the one element with a given value of `position`.
2. use `owner.elements<<` to create a new pairing between a known element and an owner, but at the same time giving to the link a weight/position.

The only think that I have been able to workout is to ignore through and work directly with the join_table, overloading a `[]` operator on it for sugar. One could expect that some more railistic solution exists, perhaps using scopes with parameters, but I do not see how I could pass a position attribute to the `create` or `<<` operations.

Given that the element is perfectly idenfified by the owner and the position, a solution with some kind of dynamical parameter in `has_one through` would be valid too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should try some dry and clean approach by defining a scope in your model.

```
scope :by_position, ->(element) { joins(:pairs).where(pairs: { position: element.position}) }
```

Giving you an idea not what exactly you wish to do, But I hope this will lead to your requirements.

Comment: scope is an interesting technique, I must still try how does it work for creation. Never sure if some id is going to be forgot as nil :-)

Answer (score 3):

Querying is easy

```
owner.elements.where(pairs: { position: 1 })
```

adding also

```
element = Element.new(name: ...)
owner.pairs << Pair.create(element: element, position: 1)
```

Comment: I want to avoid pairs because an owner has a collection of elements that just happen to be ordered by weight (or position). In my opinion, if Pair.create is the way to go, then which is the point of inventing `through`?

Comment: Could `owner.elements.where(pairs: { position: 1 }) << Element.create()` work? Or  `owner.elements.where(pairs: { position: 1 }).create()` ?